# angular material autocomplete - how to prevent keyboard enter to select an option in the suggestion panel

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I want to be able to implement a custom enter behaviour for material autocomplete when hitting the enter key while having an active option selected via arrowkeys.

Currently I have a directive (preventEnterDirective) binded to the same input element where matAutocomplete sits. And I'm preventing the default when keydown.enter emits. But the selection is already being done, when keydown.enter emits.

```html
<input preventEnterDirective type="text" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="searchInputControl" type="text">
```

```js
@HostListener('keydown.enter', ['$event']) public onEnter(evt: KeyboardEvent) {
    evt.preventDefault();
}
```

EDIT

Here is a stackblitz repo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txehk4-sic3ej

EDIT 2

I dug a little bit deeper into the source code of angular's autocomplete directive and found this on line 379 in autocomplete-trigger.ts

```js
  _handleKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    const keyCode = event.keyCode;
    ...
    if (this.activeOption && keyCode === ENTER && this.panelOpen) {
      this.activeOption._selectViaInteraction();
      this._resetActiveItem();
      event.preventDefault();
    } else if (this.autocomplete) {
      const prevActiveItem = this.autocomplete._keyManager.activeItem;
      const isArrowKey = keyCode === UP_ARROW || keyCode === DOWN_ARROW;

      if (this.panelOpen || keyCode === TAB) {
        this.autocomplete._keyManager.onKeydown(event);
      } else if (isArrowKey && this._canOpen()) {
        this.openPanel();
      }

      if (isArrowKey || this.autocomplete._keyManager.activeItem !== prevActiveItem) {
        this._scrollToOption();
      }
    }
  }
```

so basically I have two different directives which binds to an input element and have listeners with preventDefault() called.

Comment: Have you tried `return false` inside your `@HostListener`?

Comment: yep, and I'm beginning to suspect, that the enter submit ist not being trigger on the input element, but rather on some other dom element created by the autocomplete component

Comment: So then you need to put your `@HostListener` inside component and each time when you get the event, you need to check the `event.target` if it matches with your autocomplete element then `return false`.

Comment: Please create a [Stackblitz](http://stackblitz.com) project for the same, it would be easy for everyone to solve that and answer you.

Comment: You need to stopPropagation()

Comment: @bryan60 no use, since both diretives are sitting on the same dom element

Answer (score 2):

Please remove your code `autoActiveFirstOption="true"` from your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txehk4-sic3ej) code then it will surely work.

Comment: Nope... I have already posted what might be the source issue in EDIT 2.

Comment: It (`autoActiveFirstOption="true"`) always sets first option as active item so whenever you press enter key it always (and it will always selects first item). I don't think there is any other option.

Comment: have you tried your approach in a forked stackblitz :)

Comment: Yes! and have you? @HanChe

Comment: Ok I think I wasn't precise enough with the enought. Sorry for that. I want to implement a custom enter behaviour when hitting the enter key, after I have selected an active option via arrow keys.

Comment: Ohh I see! No problem, let me think that way... but you should not have down voted :).

Comment: My bad, can you change anything in your anwser? I can't lift the downvote otherwise

Comment: @HanChe How did you achieve this?